# Getting both net6 and net7 in bin

Tags: .net, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and am working on a two-stage Dockerfile [following this guide](https://andrewlock.net/optimising-asp-net-core-apps-in-docker-avoiding-manually-copying-csproj-files-part-2/).

I'm basing my build stage on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.101-alpine3.16-amd64`

After restoring (`RUN dotnet restore`) and publishing (`RUN dotnet publish "./MyWeb/MyWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app --no-restore`) I am seeing both `net6.0/` and `net7.0/` folders in "./MyWeb/bin/Debug" and "./MyWeb/bin/Release"

In addition to having files for both version of .Net, how come I also have a `Debug/` directory if I published with the Release configuration?

Comment: Instead of using a 4 year old article check the official documentation, eg [Tutorial: Containerize a .NET app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows). The image won't contain a `bin` folder at all. Your project folder will contain the same `bin` folders it always does. In a two-stage build, the *build* image will have those folders but the final image will only have what you explicitly copy with COPY.

Comment: In .NET 7 you can publish [directly to a Docker image](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-builtin-container-support-for-the-dotnet-sdk/). `dotnet publish` will use a two-stage process automatically